# How extension methods hook up

Tags: c#, .net

I was just curious to know how Extension methods are hooked up to the Original class. I know in IL code it gives a call to Static Method, but how it does that and why dosen't it break encapsulation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Extension methods are specified by putting the `this` keyword in front of the first parameter of a static method:

```
public static void SomeExtension(this string s)
{
    ...
}
```

That is just syntactic sugar for decorating the method with [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx):

```
[Extension]
public static void SomeExtension(string s)
{
    ...
}
```

When the compiler sees that attribute, it knows to translate the extension method call to the appropriate static method call, passing the instance as the first parameter.

Since the calls are just normal static method calls, there is no chance to break encapsulation; the methods, like all static methods, only have access to the public interfaces of the extended types.

Answer (score 16):

They don't "hook up".

The Visaul Studio IDE just makes it look like it does by showing them in the intellisense lists.

The compiler "knows" how to deal with the references in order to make the right method calls with the correct parameters.

This is simply [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) - the methods are simply static methods on a separate static class. Using the [`this`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) modifier lets the compiler "know" to add the [`ExtensionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.extensionattribute.aspx) to the class to mark it as an extension method.

Since extension methods do **not** in fact *change* the class and can only access public members on it, encapsulation is retained.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

> Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called **as if** they were instance methods on the extended type.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 4):

Extension methods are just syntactic sugar, they are just static methods. You are only able to access public fields or properties in them, just like normal static methods.

Answer (score 2):

The key ingredient is that an instance method of a class isn't fundamentally different from a static method.  With one small detail, they have a hidden argument.  For example, the String.IndexOf(char) method actually looks like this to the CLR:

```
public static int IndexOf(string thisRef, char value) {
   // etc...
}
```

The *thisRef* argument is what supplies the string reference whenever you use *this* in your code or access a member of the class.  As you can see, it is a *very* small step from an extension method to an instance method.  No changes were necessary in the CLR to support the feature.

One other minor difference is that the compiler emits code that checks if *this* is null for an instance method but does not do so for an extension method.  You can call an extension method on a null object.  While that might look like a feature, it is actually a restriction induced by the extension method not actually being a member of the class.

Internally, the CLR keeps a list of methods for the class, the MethodTable.  Extension methods are not in them, preventing the compiler from emitting the *callvirt* IL instruction, the 'trick' that it uses to get the cheap null check.  Explicitly emitting code to make the null check would have been possible but they elected not to do so.  Not quite sure why.

Another automatic consequence of this is that an extension method cannot be virtual.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=112388